# How to execute TestSteps using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have a Project in Soapui with: a TestSuite1, TestCase1 and some TestStep like Groovy test, Create Rep and Delay

What i want to do is to execute the Create Rep TestStep using groovy.
I tried this:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = testRunner.testCase;
def testStep = testCase.getTestStepAt(0);
def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("Create Rep");
def testStep = testCase.testSteps["Delay"];
testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, null);
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
testStep.run(testRunner, testStepContext);
```

And i got this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script15.groovy: 27:
   The current scope already contains a variable of the name testStep @ line 27, column 5.
      def testStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("");
          ^ org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: The current scope already contains a variable of the name testStep @ line 27, column 5.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:146)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you got too many testStep variables with actual same name

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
def testCase = testRunner.testCase;
def testStep1 = testCase.getTestStepAt(0);
def testStep2 = testCase.getTestStepByName("Create Rep");
def testStep3 = testCase.testSteps["Delay"];
testRunner = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, null);
testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);
testStep.run(testRunner, testStepContext);
```

Comment: Getting error on testStepContext = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext(testStep);         No Such property testStep